# SSH keys not working on OpenElec (login without typing password)

Tags: ssh, openelec

I have installed OpenElec 5.0.5 on a Pi (2), fresh install.

I enabled ssh, no problem logging-in, but I want to login without a password.
So I copied my ssh key:

```
ssh-copy-id "root@192.168.0.10x"
```

It created a .ssh directory on the Pi with a `authorized_keys` file.

Still when I try to login afterwards, it requests a password.
What´s wrong?

Comment: Did you tried with an other user than root ? root access is often disabled check `PermitRootLogin` property in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: It sounds more like it is configured to demand a password regardless, but it is still that `sshd_config` file you need to change.  Post the entire thing and I might be able to point the things out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by setting ownership of the /storage folder to root:

```
chown root: /storage
```

It was owned by 1000, dunno why.

Now it works. Found the [ownership hint  here](http://openelec.tv/forum/134-usage/68652-how-to-connect-with-ssh-keys-with-putty)

**Updated**:
Also check: permissions on /storage should be 755

`chmod 755 /storage`

Comment: In my case changing the ownership of /storage to root:root was not enough. I also had to remove write permissions for the group to /storage (755)